# Is the vector representation the fundamental representation of the Lorentz Group?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, definition, representation-theory

The vector representation of the Lorentz Group has dimension 4, while the group has dimension 6. If it's not the fundamental representation, which one is?

Comment: If you define the fundamental representation as the identity homomorphism, then one can interpret vector representation of $SO(1,d)$ as the fundamental one. Dimensions don't have to match in order for a representation to be 'fundamental' (precise definition is needed), e.g. $\mathrm{dim}\,SU(2) = 3$ while matrices in $SU(2)$ are clearly $2\times 2$.

Comment: What definition of “fundamental representation” are you using? The mathematical definition is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_representation).

Comment: I think the answer depends on whether you are considering *projective* representations (which one normally does in quantum field theory) or not.

Comment: It's the *adjoint* representation that has the same dimension as a Lie group, because it is a representation of the Lie group over its own algebra.